# Redirect to specific page after form success

Tags: php

I'm a total beginner and I don't know how to redirect to specific page after from success :

```
if ( !empty($errors)) {
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['errors']  = $errors;
}
else{

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/contacts",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '{"email":"'.$email.'", "updateEnabled":true, "listIds":[8], "attributes" : {"NOM":"'.$nom.'", "NIVEAU":"'.$niveau.'", "OPT-IN_METHOD":"FORMULAIRE"}}',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "accept: application/json",
            "api-key: KEY ",
            "content-type: application/json"
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    }
    $data['success'] = true;
    $data['message'] = 'Success!';
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

}

I tried many solutions but I'm totally lost.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Where your form is processed (after which you try to redirect to some page)? What did you try for redirection?

Comment: The last line of code would imply that you are sending a response back to a browser as an ajax reply. In this case you would redirect in the calling JavaScript. But you haven’t included that code, so that’s about as far as I can go. The other possibility is that your browser was pointed at this page, in which case the json encoded reply is meaningless because you would issue a `header(‘Location: http://target_url’);` and the json response would be unused